# python3 requirements.txt file shows unwanted packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, requirements.txt, python-venv

I created a virtual environment using : `python3 -m venv .`
I then used the command `pip freeze requirements.txt` to get the list of packages.

Below is the content of the file requirements.txt

```
apsw==3.16.2.post1
asn1crypto==0.24.0
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
chardet==3.0.4
CherryPy==8.9.1
configparser==3.5.0
cryptography==2.1.4
cssselect==1.0.3
cssutils==1.0.2
dnspython==1.15.0
enum34==1.1.6
feedparser==5.2.1
flake8==3.5.0
html5-parser==0.4.4
html5lib==0.999999999
idna==2.6
ipaddress==1.0.17
jedi==0.11.1
keyring==10.6.0
keyrings.alt==3.0
lxml==4.2.1
Markdown==2.6.9
mccabe==0.6.1
mechanize==0.2.5
msgpack==0.5.6
mysql-connector-python==8.0.6
mysql-utilities==1.6.4
netifaces==0.10.4
numpy==1.14.5
olefile==0.45.1
paramiko==2.0.0
parso==0.1.1
pep8==1.7.1
pexpect==4.2.1
Pillow==5.1.0
pyasn1==0.4.2
pycodestyle==2.3.1
pycrypto==2.6.1
pyflakes==1.6.0
Pygments==2.2.0
pygobject==3.26.1
pyodbc==4.0.17
pyOpenSSL==17.5.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
pysqlite==2.7.0
python-dateutil==2.6.1
pyxdg==0.25
PyYAML==3.12
regex==2017.12.12
repoze.lru==0.7
Routes==2.4.1
SecretStorage==2.3.1
simplejson==3.13.2
six==1.11.0
unity-lens-photos==1.0
uTidylib==0.3
virtualenv==15.2.0
webencodings==0.5
WebOb==1.7.3
```

I am not sure which packages are required for the project. Much of the packages seem not required for the project. Why is the requirements.txt showing so many packages? How to fix this so that requirements.txt shows a list of packages required for a particular project?(I could manually remove them but why are they shown in requirements.txt in the first place ?)

Note : Previously I used to install packages by `sudo apt-get install python3-package-name`. **Has this caused a permanent install of the packages and is duplicated in the virtual environment created via `python -m venv .`? Or are these default and mandatory packages?**

OS : ubuntu 18.04,
python version : 3.6.5,
pip version : 9.0.1

Comment: `pip freeze` just dumps the list of all packages installed in current virtualenv (or system-wide if no virtualenv is active). There is no magic nor smart behavior involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can list only locally installed packages using '-l' argument.
`$ pip freeze -l`

Reference: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical problem with using pip and requirements.txt to manage your packages. The new [Pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) project has addressed this problem by making a "lockfile" containing all the dependencies of the packages you're actually using from a development perspective. This is common in package managers from other languages like Bundler and npm.

So, I suggest migrating to Pipenv if this requirements.txt becomes too much to manage.